# How can the limit exist for a function on an interval (a,b) but not be continuous on that interval?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

This is from a practice test true/false question. The statement I was given is that

> If $\lim_{(x,y)→(a,b)} f(x, y)$ exists, then $f(x, y)$ is continuous at $(a, b)$.

I put True but the answer is False. I don't see how how this can be untrue?

Comment: To be continuous, $f(a, b)$ must equal that limit.

Comment: @Nishant How can it not be?

Comment: @Zardo$f$ can be everywhere equal to $0$ except in $(a,b)$ where it has $1$ for value as an example.

Comment: A simpler 2D example is a function like $f (x) = \frac{x^2-1}{x-1}$ near the point 1

Comment: Well I alrady rid myself of the previous comment to be replaced with just a simple example (which can serve as a simplified counter example) as to why the limit and function also need to agree

Comment: In my case the limit exists but the function isnt continous

Comment: @grasshopper
Take this very simplified example for a better mental image. [IMAGE] {http://i.imgur.com/xowbpAu.png}. Forgive the bad MS Paint.

Comment: @Dan I slightly disagree. Your function simply isn't defined at $1$, which is different from being continuous. In fact a sensible definition of the function at $1$ makes it continuous.

Comment: Yes but the function as defined fits as a counter example to thinking that just because a limit exists that conveys continuity, that was the essence of the question. With a reasonable definition yeah of course it works, but that would be a different function that satisfies the definition of continuity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must also have $$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (a,b)} f(x,y) = f(a,b)$$ to ensure  the continuity at $(a,b)$.

Comment: If the limit of the function exists though, every seqence $f(x_n,y_n)$ with $(x_n,y_n) \to (x,y)$ has to converge to it. This is equivalent to sequential continuity!

Comment: @Zardo True if the function is supposed to be continuous. Which is not the case if the limit is not equal to its value at the considered point.

Comment: It's a strange idea to define the limit $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \chi_{\{(0,0)\}}(x,y)$ to be $0$. This is not how I know it.

Comment: @Zardo This is the definition of the limit https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function

Comment: But then my previous limit is wrong, isn't it? If $f$ is defined at $(a,b)$ then it has to equal the limit!

Comment: @Zardo. If you cope to standard definitions... Which is better to communicate easily, then yes your previous limit has to vanish.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24931/discussion-between-jean-pierre-merx-and-zardo).